# Is there a halacha [either modesty or taharah] against more than one woman at a time immersing in a mikvah for T'vilah?

Tags: halacha, tznius-modesty, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, mikvah-ritual-bath, niddah

Is there a halacha [in either modesty law or *taharah* law] against more than one woman at a time immersing in a mikvah for *t'vilah*, (ritual imersion), (If each woman's *tvilah* was supervised properly by another woman?)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78172/discussion-on-question-by-ribbisrabbiandmore-is-there-a-halacha-either-modesty).